# VBA - cells color

Tags: excel, vba, colors

What is wrong with this code?
I get an "ARG!" error

```
Public Function nr_kolor(kom As Range)  
  For Each komorka In kom
    wartosc = komorka.Font.Color
    wiersz = komorka.Row
    kolumna = komorka.Column + 3
    nr_kolor = wartosc
  Next komorka
  activesheet.Cells(wiersz, kolumna).Select
  Selection.Interior.Color = wartosc  
End Function
```

Comment: You need to spedify WHAT are you trying to accomplish and also what error do you get.

Answer (score 3):

There are a lot of things you are doing wrong.

- You have failed to declare your variables.
- You need to use a **Sub()** not **Function().** As a rule, functions are not allowed to alter the worksheet in any way, just manipulate and return values.
- Your loop has errors - if you wish to do things to more than one cell than all your instructions need to be within the loop. Right now it only colors 1 cell (3 columns right of the LAST cell in your range).
- You are returning the function before the function is over.

I think what you are trying to do (there was no explanation) is take a range of cells, and apply the same interior color to the cells three columns over. Here is a more effecient way to do this. I have purposly kept the logic simple.

```
Sub ColorCells()

Dim cell As Range

For Each cell In Range("A1:A10")
    cell.Offset(, 3).Interior.Color = cell.Interior.Color
Next

End Sub
```

**How it works**:
You create a variable cell as a range, this will represent each cell in the range you supply. For each cell in the range, you want to apply the same interior color to the cell OFFSET 3 columns to the right.

Comment: Try `Range("A1:A10").Offset(0, 3).Interior.Color = cell.Interior.Color`. It is faster than a Loop.

Comment: Functions can not modify the worksheet ONLY if called from the worksheet; as a User Defined Formula.  If you use the Function inside a main procedure you can do everything.

Comment: I purposely kept the logic similar to what the OP had. And calling a function inside of a procedure does not change the fact that it's not allowed to alter the worksheet.